# How do I prove this statement in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a test about a week ago and I want to know the answer to this question:

Given an orthonormal basis $B$ spanned by $\{ v_1, v_2 , v_3 \}$ of ${\mathbb R}^3$

Prove that for every $v \in {\mathbb R}^3$ then 
$\left \|  
\begin{bmatrix}
v
\end{bmatrix}_B   
\right \| = \left \| v  \right \|$

Comment: What do you mean by $||[v]_B||$?

Comment: @smcc you right, I edited the question

Comment: @Ashvin: The (length of the) coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Write $v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 a_i v_i$ and compute $v\cdot v$.

Comment: How writing $v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3$ helps me to compute $v \cdot v$?

Comment: Just expand it out, using the algebraic properties of dot product.

Comment: @LiziPizi because $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is an **orthonormal** set, some very nice cancellations will occur.

Comment: @TedShifrin plz show me how to do it, I don't really understand what you want me to do

Comment: Your textbook surely tells you algebraic properties of dot product. For example, $v\cdot w = w\cdot v$, $(cv)\cdot w = c(v\cdot w)$, $(u+v)\cdot w = u\cdot w + v\cdot w$, etc. Use them.

Comment: I got to $\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2$, how does it help me?

Comment: Great! You're done. Look what your question was asking! (You need to know what $[v]_B$ means.)